# Why is state readonly in Parent class if I extend a Child class from Parent in React (Typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, inheritance, covariance

I have created an interface for Parent class defined for State:

```
interface ParentState { name: string; }
```

I have created a component with state of above mentioned type:

```
class Test extends React.Component<{}, ParentState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    // Works fine!
    this.state = { name: '' };
  }
}
```

This is working as expected. However, If I create a parent and a child component, where the child component inherits from parent and child state inherits from parent state, the state in parent becomes readonly.

```
interface ChildState extends ParentState {}

class Parent<P, S extends ParentState> extends React.Component<P, S> {
  constructor(props: P) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { name: '' };
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    // Compilation error!
    // TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.
  }

  render() {
    return <div>parent</div>;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent<{}, ChildState> {
  constructor(props: ChildProps) {
  super(props);

    // Works fine!
    this.state = { name: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>child</div>;
  }
}
```

Can someone explain this behaviour.

P.S.

I have a couple more of questions.

1. Also, in React library, when I open the index.d.ts file, the **state** is actually **readonly**. How is this working in the class Test mentioned earlier?
2. If I do not mention type for props in constructor in Test class, there is a compilation error saying

   ```
   TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.
   ```

   Why doesn't it take type `{}` mentioned in the class definition?

Comment: The last bit (#1) is easy: [`readonly`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier) properties are expected to be initialized in the constructor.

Comment: How sure are you that `this.state = {}` is fine in the `Test` case, and doesn't tell you "`property 'name' is missing in type '{}'`"?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, my bad. I have edited the question now. My intention was to demonstrate that this.state is still assignable in Test class. But it is not working in a similar manner in Parent class.

Comment: #2: because the constructor of a child class doesn't need to look anything like the constructor of the parent class, so the compiler has no idea what type the `props` parameter must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is something like:

```
Type '{ name: string }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.
```

That is telling you that if you have a variable of type `Readonly<S>`, then it is not safe to assign a value of type `{ name: string }` to it.  Let's see why.

Since `S` is generic, code you write with it needs to be compatible with substituting any valid concrete type for `S`.  The constraint on `S` is `S extends ParentState`, so let's come up with a type that meets that constraint and instantiate `Parent` with it:

```
interface ProblemChildState extends ParentState {
  naughtiness: true
}
const problemComponent = new Parent<{}, ProblemChildState>({});
```

Let's imagine what that constructor is doing, now that `S` has been concretely specified as `ProblemChildState`:

```
this.state = { name: '' }; // oops!
```

The type of `this.state` is `Readonly<ProblemChildState>`, but as you can see, the value `{ name: '' }` is not a valid `ProblemChildState` at all, because it's missing the `naughtiness` property.

Since that assignment is invalid for the concrete `ProblemChildState`, the assignment must be invalid for the generic `S`.  Hence the error.

In practice it's hard to assign a literal value to a variable of a generic type.  Even in the rare cases where you can come up with something that works for all possible instantiations of the generic type parameter, the compiler is likely to give you an error because the situation is too rare for it to check, and you'll need to do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Indeed, you can work around the issue by doing such an assertion:

```
this.state = { name: '' } as Readonly<S>; // not safe!
```

but that isn't safe for the reason mentioned above.  Ideally you'd alter your code not to require setting `state` until you have a concrete type for `S`.  Possibly by making `Parent` an `abstract` class?

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!